# Improving controls of Raspberry Pi RC robot

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, robotics

I'm currently working on a basic Raspberry pi project and I need help with improving the controls for it.

This is my current code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import curses

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.OUT)

screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
screen.keypad(True)

try:
    while True:
        char = screen.getch()
        if char == curses.KEY_UP:
            GPIO.output(11,True)
            GPIO.output(13,True)
        elif char == ord('s'): 
            GPIO.output(7,False)
            GPIO.output(11,False)
            GPIO.output(13,False)
            GPIO.output(15,False)
            break
        elif char == curses.KEY_DOWN:
            GPIO.output(7,True)
            GPIO.output(15,True)
        elif char == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
            GPIO.output(7,True)
            GPIO.output(13,True)
        elif char == curses.KEY_LEFT:
            GPIO.output(11,True)
            GPIO.output(15,True)
        elif char == 10:
            GPIO.output(7,False)
            GPIO.output(11,False)
            GPIO.output(13,False)
            GPIO.output(15,False)
finally:
    curses.nocbreak()
    screen.keypad(False)
    curses.echo()
    curses.endwin()
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

The problem that I have is that it requires me to press the enter key to stop the motors and change direction and the way that I would like to have it set up is so that, for example, when the up key is **pressed and held** the motor moves forward and **once the key is released the motors stop.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is it only changes the GPIO when a button is pushed. This is because `getch()` What you want is to

In order to get the behavior you want you need to have `getch()` return a value even when no button is pressed. There are two ways to do this

1. **nodelay**: this makes getch() return immediately, whether or not a key is pressed, if no key is pressed it will return *curses.ERR*
2. **halfdelay**: this makes getch() wait upto a set amount of time, if no key is pressed in that time period it returns *curses.ERR*

The similarity is both will return *curses.ERR* when no button is pushed, so you need to add that case to your if statement

```
#this will shut off the GPIO when nothing is pushed
elif char == curses.ERR:
    GPIO.output(7,False)
    GPIO.output(11,False)
    GPIO.output(13,False)
    GPIO.output(15,False)
```

But that code won't work until you do the setup. Replace the **cbreak** mode with whichever mode we are using

## Method 1: nodelay

The advantage of this method is that it is nearly instantaneous. As soon as you let go of a key the bot should stop. 
Disadvantage, this may consume a lot of processing power. Since it will execute the loop very quickly, set GPIOs very quickly, read key quickly, etc it will do many cycles while not achieving much real work

```
screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.nodelay(True)
screen.keypad(True)
```

## Method 2: halfdelay

The advantage of this method is it should lower the processor usage compared to nodelay method. 
The disadvantage is there is a delay after you release a key. So after  you release the key the bot would continue executing the previous command for some time (in my sample code .7 seconds) before it stops

```
#the delay units are tenths of seconds, or deciseconds
#this is a .7 second delay 7*0.10sec = 0.7 seconds
delay_in_deciseconds = 7 

screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.halfdelay(delay_in_deciseconds)
screen.keypad(True)
```